# Outlook addin is not showing in ItemRead mode

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am loading an Office.js outlook addin (hello-world-addin sample https://github.com/jasonjoh/hello-world-addin) in my web account. The addin seems to be working fine in my old outlook account. However, if i test it in new outlook account, the addin doesnt show at all the Incoming folder (email read). Does anybody knows how to solve that issue?

Comment: Can you share your manifest?

Comment: I am using the manifest directly from the sample (by changing of course the URL)

Comment: Is your new account an Exchange 2013+/Office 365 mailbox?

Comment: Just plain outlook accounts. The only difference is that the first is old one and the second new one

Comment: Did you sideload the add-in manifest into your "new" account?

Comment: I did in both ways. Loading manifest locally and from https server. The result is always the same and tested on many accounts. Hence, I start to believe that MS is dropping support for it.

Comment: What do you mean by "plain Outlook accounts"? If these aren't Exchange 2013+ or Office 365 accounts then add-ins won't load